# How do I reference clients and not sockets with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to learn express and socket.io and haven't been able to find an answer to my question. I need to reference clients and not sockets, and since I have multiple pages connecting to the server it creates different sockets so I can't keep track of users. What is the proper way to do this? I haven't been able to find a solution that made sense

In essence all I want to do is be able to reference the same client no matter what page they are on with my server. But if I have two separate snippets of code like this to keep track of users it doesn't work

```
socket.on('set name', function (name) {
    console.log("set name My socket id is " + socket.id);
    socket.set('username', name);
    socket.get('username', function (error, value) {
        console.log("set name Socket.username " + value);
    });
});
```

and later

```
socket.on('getusername', function () {
    console.log("getusername My socket id is " + socket.id);
    socket.get('username', function (error, value) {
        console.log("getusername Socket.username " + value);
    });
});
```

The second code being called from a different page, what are my options to reference the client rather than the sockets?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of rooms in socket.io.

All sockets with same name can going a room.

Something like this:

```
socket.on('set name', function (name) {
    socket.join(name);
});
```

and later

```
socket.on('getusername', function () {
    // get all the rooms socket is part of and use the
    // first room he is in.
    var room = io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id][0];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try set the browser cookie on the client (the one that will be deleted when user closes the browser) and send its value in message payload when you initialize the socket connection.